# How to vectorize this simple NumPy function?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Given the function:

```
def f(x, c=0.7):
    if x >= 0:
        if x <= c:
            return 0.0
        if x <= 2*c:
            return x-c
        else:
            return c
    else:
        return -f(-x, c=c)
```

I would like to apply it to NumPy arrays. I used to do that with `np.vectorize`, but I'm failing. What's the idea here?

Comment: What did you try? What error message do you get?

Comment: Got it now. It works for arrays but not for array of arrays (matrices) if element-wise is intended

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to point out the following from the documentation on [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

So, actually, you do NOT make use of NumPy's vectorization abilities here. Using NumPy's [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), you can rewrite your function, such that you have "real" vectorization.

Here's an idea from my side. The actual code looks quite ugly, I have to admit, but by pre-calculating the boolean arrays, we minimize processing time and memory usage.

```py
def f_vec(x, c=0.7):

    # Initialize output array of same size and type as input array
    out = np.zeros_like(x)

    # Pre-calculate boolean arrays to prevent multiple calculation in following steps
    x_gtq_0 = (x >= 0)
    x_lt_0 = (x < 0)
    x_gt_c = (x > c)
    x_ltq_2c = (x <= 2 * c)
    x_gt_2c = (x > 2 * c)
    abs_x = np.abs(x)
    abs_x_gt_c = abs_x > c
    abs_x_ltq_2c = abs_x <= 2 * c
    abs_x_gt_2c = (abs_x > 2 * c)

    # Re-writing if-else blocks as operations on before calculated boolean arrays
    out[np.where(x_gtq_0 & x_gt_c & x_ltq_2c)] = x[np.where(x_gtq_0 & x_gt_c & x_ltq_2c)] - c
    out[np.where(x_gtq_0 & x_gt_2c)] = c
    out[np.where(x_lt_0 & abs_x_gt_c & abs_x_ltq_2c)] = c - abs_x[np.where(x_lt_0 & abs_x_gt_c & abs_x_ltq_2c)]
    out[np.where(x_lt_0 & abs_x_gt_2c)] = -c

    return out
```

I added the following, small test function to run some comparisons:

```py
def test(x):

    print(x.shape)
    vfunc = np.vectorize(f)

    tic = time.perf_counter()
    res_func = vfunc(x, c=0.7)
    print(time.perf_counter() - tic)

    tic = time.perf_counter()
    res_vec = f_vec(x, c=0.7)
    print(time.perf_counter() - tic)

    print('Differences: ', np.count_nonzero(np.abs(res_func - res_vec) > 10e-9), '\n')


test((np.random.rand(10) - 0.5) * 4)
test((np.random.rand(1000, 1000) - 0.5) * 4)
test((np.random.rand(1920, 1280, 3) - 0.5) * 4)
```

These are the results:

```
(10,)
0.0001590869999999467
7.954300000001524e-05
Differences:  0 

(1000, 1000)
1.53853834
0.0843256779999999
Differences:  0 

(1920, 1280, 3)
10.974010127
0.7489308680000004
Differences:  0
```

So, performance-wise the difference between `np.vectorize` and an actual vectorized approach is huge for larger inputs. Nevertheless, if the `np.vectorize` solution is sufficient for your inputs, and you don't want put too much effort into re-writing your code, stick to that! As I said, I just wanted to show, that vectorization is more than that.

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

This function works with yours just fine. Try it:

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(f)
vfunc(a, c=0.7)
```

If you still get errors - pls post them with input data example